# Chrome extension not editing page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension for the site [PCPartPicker](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu). It should find each product and then the `<p>` element inside of it to get the name of it and then take that name and add " - Hello there!" to the end of it.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    var name = items[i].getElementsByTagName('p');
    name[0].innerText = name + ' - Hello there!';
}
```

Comment: It probably means the elements are added dynamically. Use `MutationObserver` to detect them.

Comment: I am really new to JavaScript, could you provide more info and possibly give code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your extension runs on all pages of the said website i.e. pcpartpicker.com, something like this should work in your case.

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  if(window.location.pathname.includes('/product/cpu')) {
    startObserver();
  }
}

const startObserver = () => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.productList--detailed');
  var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
  const observer = new MutationObserver(changeProductName);
  observer.observe(elem, config); 
}

const changeProductName = (mutationList, observer) => {
  mutationList.forEach( (mutation) => {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach( (node) => {
      if(node.nodeName === 'TR') {
        var name = node.getElementsByTagName('p');
        name[0].innerText = name + ' - Hello there!';
      }
    })
  })
}
```

As wOxxOm suggested, we're making use of `MutationObserver` to observe the changes to table having class `productList--detailed`. Whenever any new `tr` element is added, the code modifies the text inside the first `p` element of the newly added `tr`. You can read more about `MutationObserver` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: This returns the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onCompleted')

Comment: You need to add `webNavigation` permission inside the `permissions` array of the `manifest.json` file for this to work. See edit.

Comment: I added `"permissions": ["webNavigation"],` to the Manifest.json, but it's still giving the same error. It highlighted the first line in the error, if that helps.

Comment: Are you using this script in `contentScript.js` or `background.js`? `chrome.webNavigation` will only work inside `background.js`.

Comment: My bad. `MutationObserver` will not be available inside `background.js`. You can use `window.onload` event instead to wait for the DOM and resources to load before you can find the `table` element.

Comment: I am using a contentScript.js. I am guessing the main difference between the 2 is that the background one runs in the background rather than running with a higher priority. Is that correct?

Comment: I changed the code to what you edited it to. It fixed the error, but nothing is happening.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind, fixed it by changing the matches to include products/cpu/* and removing the if statement checking for it.